# Material UI apply dark theme

Tags: material-ui

I have been searching the web for a while, but I could not understand how to apply the default dark theme that is shown in the site of Material-ui, where you can toggle between the light and dark theme.
They say those are default ones, but how do I use them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them by creating a Theme like this:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const THEME = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
  },
});

class YourComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={THEME}>
        ... your other components
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

The toggle can be done with a button like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wz9r8330p7?from-embed).